# After installing FCM plugin, build failes

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, google-play-services, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am trying to implement push notification by FCM in Ionic3. i have followed everything as in [Ionic FCM docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/). everything went smoothly but when i tried to build then i got the error below. How to fix this , thanks in advance.

```
    BUILD FAILED
    Total time: 2.138 secs
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
    > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information
    about the latest version is available at
    https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of
    com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to your `plugins` folder and open up the folder of the fcm plugin. Then you navigate to `src/android` and open `FCMPlugin.gradle` and change the following line:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

To this one

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

Save the file, then remove the android platform (`cordova platform rm android`) and add it again (`cordova platform add android`).

Comment: Then one of your other plugins is using a different versioin of the google-services. You will have to find out which one and change the version to the same one.